# How to differentiate json null and an empty json array in an MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

One of my controllers accepts different json data to update my user info.

Some `json` is to update the password

```
{Id:1, NewPassword:'xxx'}
```

Some `json` is to update the roles of a user

```
{Id:1, Roles:['admin', 'guest']}
```

What I have set up in the controller is to detect if there is values in NewPassword and Roles .

```
if (userinfo.NewPassword != null)
{
    _repository.SetNewPassword(user.UserName, serinfo.NewPassword);                    
}
if (userinfo.Roles != null) 
{                    
    string[] roles = userinfo.Roles.ToArray();
    _repository.UpdateRolesForUser(user.UserName,roles);
}
```

It works fine except in one condition: when I remove all roles from a user. In that case, the json sent over is

```
{Id: 1, Roles:[]}
```

Then `userinfo.Roles != null` returns a `false` and `_repository.UpdateRolesForUser(user.UserName,roles);` is therefore never reached.

My question: how to detect the difference between a `Roles:[]` and a "true null"? Is there a function like `has` or `exists`?

-----Update-----
This controller is an `ApiController` and the code is in the `PUT` action. Therefore, all types of json have to enter this single action. Otherwise, it would be very convenient that we can make Ajax calls to different actions.

Comment: You can have more than one PUT action. Just put the [HttpPut] attribute above it if you only want it to handle PUT requests.

Comment: But is it a good practice to have multiple PUT?

Comment: sure why not?  As your code sits right now, you are violating the Single Responsibility Principle.  Having multiple PUT is no different that having multiple POST or GET actions.

Comment: I think it's worse practice to have to guess on the server side what kind of operation is being performed based on what data is getting passed in. Create a new action and save yourself some grief

Answer (score 0):

I would create two controller actions for this.  An Update Password Action and an Update Roles Action.  This will clean up your controller action and simplify things.

If you make a call to the Update Roles method and the Roles[] is NullOrEmpty you will no that the user has no roles as opposed to guessing what the intent of the client was.

On the alternative you could write a custom model binder that differentiates an empty array from a null value.

Comment: I cannot create different actions. Please see the updates section. Can you please clarify the other two solutions? It obviously is what we need but how to implement?

Comment: See if this helps: http://sweettam.blogspot.com/2012/04/interesting-json-model-binding.html